# 2 x criteria for Match showing no results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to show results where the sum of records is greater or equal to 4 and the status matches a string. If I leave off the `status` field it works fine but adding it in always gives me an empty array even when there should be data.

```
const bookings = await Booking.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y/%m/%d",
                    date: "$bookingDate",
                },
            },
            totalBookings: {
                $sum: 1,
            },
        },
  },
    {
        $match: {
            totalBookings: {
                $gte: 4,
            },
            status: "Accepted",
        },
  },
]);
```

Comment: In your `$group` stage, you only included `_id` and `totalBookings`. So when you `$match` by status, it will not match any record. Try to include the status field in your `$group` stage(likely by `$first`) and you should get your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each booking will have it's own status. So you need to add that as part of `$group`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        status: "$status",
        "d": {
          $dateToString: {
            format: "%Y/%m/%d",
            date: "$bookingDate",
            
          }
        },
        
      },
      totalBookings: {
        $sum: 1,
        
      },
      
    }
  }
```

Then you need to change your match as below

```
 $match: {
            totalBookings: {
                $gte: 4,
            },
            "_id.status": "Accepted",
        }
```

It will give you all the Accepted Booking on the given BookinDate which is >= 4.

Comment: Thanks for that. I get the following error when implementing: `MongoServerError: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y/%m/%d", date: "$bookingDate" }, status: "$status" }`

Comment: @user8463989 my bad, please try the updated group stage from the answer.

Comment: If you still have a problem you can [edit this with sample data and share the link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sQ6a3jT0deH)

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks!